# cannot build Java programs in Geany Editor?

Tags: gnome, java, compiling, geany

Something error with **Geany** cannot build java programs.

[image]

when i click on build i get output like :-

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

**PS: Nothing problem with JDK. Run perfecly using `Javac` and `appletviewer` on terminal**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>F8</kbd> or <kbd>Build</kbd> -> <kbd>Compile</kbd> **instead of** <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F9</kbd> or <kbd>Build</kbd> -> <kbd>Make</kbd>.

After that <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Build</kbd> -> <kbd>Execute</kbd>

Comment: Build->Make is for usage with a Makefile -- not very common with Java I guess.